# Group Policy not blocking RDP saved credentials when using hostname

Tags: group-policy, rdp

Group policy is set up to prevent users from using saved credentials, works fine when connecting to the RDP via IP address or FQDN. But connecting in through just the hostname allows a user to save their credentials. How can I address this, we do not want ANY saved credentials.

Comment: Is this for all hostnames, or just some? For example, if you just type some gibberish in as the host name and attempt to connect, does it give you the option to save credentials?

Comment: It seems like its only that hostname... It does not appear that I can save credentials for anything else, even gibberish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have a .rdp file with saved credentials for that particular host. If an .rdp file already exists with saved credentials, it'll continue allowing you to use them. Look in the user's Documents folder and see if you can find the file. Deleting it should fix the problem.

Comment: That's....peculiar. I didn't create the saved credentials until a couple days after the GP was implemented. But sure enough after I deleted the credentials I had saved, I am no longer able to save credentials.

Comment: That's good 'ole Microsoft for you - inconsistent as usual. Glad it's working though.

Comment: at least they are consistent about being inconsistent :)